# How to get the $_POST from specific <select> in PHP form selected by a checkbox?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form that displays more than one record (usernames) and has a 'checkbox' for each one of them. When the user clicks on the SUBMIT button, I want to grab the information from the selected record or records. Here is what I have...

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function jqCheckAll3( id, pID )
{
   $( "#" + pID + " :checkbox").attr('checked', $('#' + id).is(':checked'));
}
//  End -->
</script>
<form name='myForm' action='adminprocess.php' method='POST'>
<table id='left' style='margin-bottom:5px;'>
<tr>
<th class='sortable'>Username</th><th class='sortable'>Name</th>
<th class='sortable'>Email</th><th class='sortable'>Level</th><th>Department</th><th class='sortable'>Registered</th><th>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkL" onclick="jqCheckAll3(this.id, 'left');"/></th>
</tr>
<?php
 while($row = $result->fetch())
 {
    $regdate = $row['regdate'];
    $reg  = date("j M, y, g:i a", $regdate);    
    echo "<tr><td><a href='".$config['WEB_ROOT']."admin/index.php?id=6&usertoedit=".$username."'>".$username."</a></td>\n";

    echo "<td>".$fname." ".$lname."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$Uemail."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>";
    ?>
    <select name="ulevel" id="ulevel">
      <option value="8">Supervisor</option>
      <option value="6">Regular user</option>
      <option value="5">Reports Only</option>
    </select>

    <?PHP
    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>\n\t";
    ?>
    <select name="departmentid" id="departmentid">
         <option value="1">North East</option>
         <option value="2">South</option>
         <option value="3">Central</option>
    </select>
    <?PHP
    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$reg."</td>\n";
    echo "echo "</td>\n";
echo "<td>".$reg."</td>\n";
echo "</td><td><input name='user_name[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row['username']."' />";
echo "</td>\n</tr>";
    echo "</td>\n</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="activateusers" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Activate Selected Users">
<br>
</form>
```

and my adminprocess.php looks like this...

```
function procActivateUsers(){
    global $session, $database, $mailer;
    $config = $database->getConfigs();
    /* Account edit attempt */

    foreach($_POST['user_name'] as $username) {
        $sql = $database->connection->prepare("UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET USERLEVEL = '".$_POST['ulevel']."', DEPTID = '".$_POST['departmentid']."' WHERE username = '$username'");
        $sql->execute();
        $req_user_info = $database->getUserInfo($username);
        $email = $req_user_info['email'];
        $mailer->adminActivated($username,$email,$config);
    }
    header("Location: ../admin/index.php?id=3");
    }
```

DO NOT worry about sanitizing or anything else at the moment, I am doing all that before. Just need to grab something like:

User 1 -> ulevel = 6 -> departmentid = 3,

User 2 -> ulevel = 4 -> departmentid = 1

Thanks for any help

Comment: is there a loop (in the html form) that we don't see here? because otherwise your question doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: oops... my copy & paste skills are not as good as before... I edited the question to show the loop.

Comment: You shouldn't prepare the statement every time through the loop. Prepare it once before the loop and use `bindParam` to bind it to variables, then call `execute()` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use array-style names for the `<select>` fields, so you'll get an array of all the selections.

You can put the username inside the brackets, so they'll be associated with the checkboxes. Also, you need to give them unique IDs, you can put the username there as well (but are you sure these elements need IDs in the first place?).

```
?>
<select name="ulevel[<?php echo $row['username'];?>]" id="ulevel-<?php echo $row['username'];?>">
  <option value="8">Supervisor</option>
  <option value="6">Regular user</option>
  <option value="5">Reports Only</option>
</select>

<?PHP
echo "</td>\n";
echo "<td>\n\t";
?>
<select name="departmentid[<?php echo $row['username'];?>]" id="departmentid-<?php echo $row['username'];?>">
     <option value="1">North East</option>
     <option value="2">South</option>
     <option value="3">Central</option>
</select>
```

Then in the PHP code, you can do:

```
$sql = $database->connection->prepare("UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET USERLEVEL = :ulevel, DEPTID = :departmentid WHERE username = :username");
$sql->bindParam($ulevel, $deptid, $username);
foreach ($_POST['user_name'] as $username) {
    $ulevel = $_POST['ulevel'][$username];
    $deptid = $_POST]['departmentid'][$username];
    $sql->execute();
    $req_user_info = $database->getUserInfo($username);
    $email = $req_user_info['email'];
    $mailer->adminActivated($username,$email,$config);
}
```

If you have an ID field in the user table, I suggest you use that instead of the username, as you then don't have to worry about potential problems from special characters (I assumed above that usernames won't contain any characters that need special encoding in HTML).